# How to escape a special character that is stored as variable from a command line argument

Tags: linux, bash

Hi I want to write a script that allows me to use any character (special included) in a command line argument. So if I called the script like so it shouldnt have errors:

```
./myscript file *
```

In the script I want look for a file in a directory with that symbol (but note it doesnt have to be that symbol could be %, @, # etc. So im using find but not sure how to escape.

```
search = $1
find=$(find $search -name "*$2")
```

If the file I look for has the symbol notify the person but if doesnt add the symbol to the directory and again im not sure how to escape it. Below is the code I use to change it but it needs to be escaped also.

```
 mv $search $search$2
```

Any ideas on escaping it, I done the usual but got odd results. i.e

```
find=$(find $search -name "*\$2")
mv $search $search\$2
```

Comment: The first line is already wrong. You *must* quote the `*` to prevent the shell from expanding it before `myscript` even starts.

Comment: What do you mean "add the symbol to the directory". Could you show an example of what commands `./myscript` *should* execute, if you replace the `$1` and `$2` with the actual values you want?

Comment: the first line is the comment line argument. In the command line I want just type `./myscript file *` are you saying I would have to type `./myscript file "*"`

Comment: It would look if the directory had a file with a symbol attached and if not it would rename it (in my example file*). If I choose a different symbol in the command line argument lets say & it would look for a file with that symbol attached so in this case the renamed directory would be file& (that is if no file in the directory contained &)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the call must look like this, to avoid the shell from expanding `*` before the script is called.

```
./myscript file '*'
```

Inside your script, it will then suffice to simply quote the parameter expansions. However, you'll have to pass a backslash to the argument to `-name` so that `find` itself does not also treat the character specially.

```
# No spaces around the equal sign!
search=$1
find=$(find "$search" -name \*\'"$2")
# ...
mv "$search" "$search$2"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work. In the case if I use the @ symbol as the argument and even though I choose a directory that has the symbol it still says added symbol. the logic seems rights:

Comment: `find=$(find $search -name \*\'"$2")

       if [ "$find" != "" ]
                then
                        echo 'Symbol exsists'

        else
                echo " symbol added"
 mv $search $search$2
        fi `